# Sequential Search returning random numbers at index variables

Tags: c

```
void introducirarray(int numeros[20], int numbusca) {
    printf("Por favor introduce el número a buscar");
    scanf("%i", &numbusca);
    char end = '0';
    for (int i = 0; i < 20 && end != '\n';) {
        scanf("%i", &numeros[i]);
        scanf("%c", &end);
    }
}

void buscador(int numeros[20], int numbusca) {
    int e = 0;
    int indexprim = 0;
    do {
        indexprim = e;
        e++;
    } while (numeros[e] != numbusca);
    printf("La primera aparición del número deseado es %i", indexprim);
}

void buscultima(int numeros[20], int numbusca) {
    int indexfin = 0;
    for (int o = 0; o < 20; o++) {
        if (numeros[o] == numbusca) {
            indexfin = o;
        }
    }
    printf("La ultima aparicion de el numero deseado es %i", indexfin);
}
```

So I kind of have an issue here. In this sequential search it should be returning to me via the `indexprim` the first appearance of a wanted number in an array, and via `indexfin` its final appearance. However the actual output is trash values.

Comment: Why does `introducirarray` take `numbusca` as a parameter if it asks for it from the user? And why doesn't it use this variable after inputting it?

Comment: To find the final appearance you should count down from 19 to 0.

Comment: I suspect the problem is with how you're setting `numbusca`. You're only assigning the local variable in `inroducirarray`, not in the caller, because parameters are passed by value, not by reference.

Comment: @communistfunnyman Show how the functions are called.

Comment: You seem to think that setting the `numbusca` parameter in `introducirarray` will somehow change its value in the caller.  It won't.  Remember, C uses pass-by-value argument passing.  So in `introducirarray`, the `numbusca` parameter is just a local variable which is set to the passed argument value when the function is called.  If you want to change it in the caller, you need to pass the address, or else return the value.

Comment: @communistfunnyman In any case the function buscador has bugs.:) It does not take into account the size of the passed array and the first element of the array is just skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- `introducirarray` may input fewer than 10 numbers into the array, but the caller has no way to know how many values were input.
- `buscador` does not stop at the end of the array: it has undefined behavior if `numbusca` is not present in the array.
- `buscultima` outputs `0` if the number is not present in the array, which is undistinguishable from the case where the number is present just once at index `0`.
- you do not test for `scanf()` failures
- you should put a newline at the end of the output.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void introducirarray(int numeros[], int size) {
    char end;
    int i;

    printf("Please enter up to %d values: ", size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (scanf("%i", &numeros[i]) != 1)
            break;
        if (scanf("%c", &end) != 1 || end == '\n')
            break;
    }
    return i;
}

void buscador(const int numeros[], int len, int numbusca) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (numeros[i] == numbusca)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;  // not found
}

void buscultima(const int numeros[], int len, int numbusca) {
    for (int i = len; i-- > 0;) {
        if (numeros[i] == numbusca)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;  // not found
}

int main() {
    int numeros[20];
    int size = sizeof numeros / sizeof numeros[0];
    int len = introducirarray(numeros, size);
   
    printf("Please enter the number to search: ");
    if (scanf("%i", &numbusca) != 1)
        return 1;

    int indexprim = buscador(numeros, len, numbusca);
    int indexfin = buscultima(numeros, len, numbusca);

    if (indexprim < 0) {
        printf("The number %d is not present in the array\n", numbusca);
    } else {
        printf("The first occurrence of %d is at index %d\n", numbusca, indexprim);
        printf("La last occurrence of %d is at index %d\n", numbusca, indexfin);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want to do

```
// ejercicio: rewrite so this function takes only one parameter int[20],
// but returns an int instead of void (main will need adjustments too)
void introducirarray(int numeros[20], int *numbusca) {
  printf("Por favor introduce el número a buscar");
  scanf("%i", numbusca);
  char end = '0';
  for (int i = 0; i < 20 && end != '\n';) {
    scanf("%i", &numeros[i]);
    scanf("%c", &end);
  }
}
int main() {
    int numbusca_main; // could be named numbusca
    int numeros[20];
    introducirarray(numeros, &numbusca_main);
    // ... more code
}
```

This way you have `numbusca_main` on the stack in main, and you can pass the pointer to it (its location) to introducirarray.

What you do in your code is you have numbusca local to the function (but set to value passed from main). If in main you have code like `int numbusca; introducirarray(..., numbusca))`, it is bad because it wasn't even initialized and is passed to the function.

Anyway, you have numbusca stored locally in the function, so `scanf(..., &numbusca)` saves to this location that disappears after the function returns. It is not the same as the outside numbusca from main.

The names of parameters at function declaration/definition and at "callsite" don't need to match, and if they do it doesn't matter.

Here is some explanation of how parameter passing works.
If you have a function defined like so:

```
void fun(int a) {
    // some code
}
```

then you can think of

```
int main() {
    fun(3);
}
```

as of

```
int main() {
    {
        int a = 3;
        // some code
    }
}
```

and of

```
int main() {
    int b = 10;
    fun(b);

    char a = 'c';
    fun(3);
}
```

as of

```
int main() {
    int b = 10;
    {
        int a = 10;
        // some code
    }
    
    char a = 'c';
    //int a = 60; would be similar // char for dramatic effect, to show how in inner scope the type can be different too -- its a brand new thing!
    // below code doesn't change this a
    {
        int a = 3;
        // some code
    }
}
```

note how a from main doesn't have anytjing to do with a from the function declaration and body.
Note that `int a = ...` from the blocks are in different scope than main (because of the block, and new declaration `int a = ...`).

There is a subtle difference between `int a =...` and `a = ...` here -- the first one declares new thing, which is legal in new block scope, the second one overrides the old thing.

So: when the function has a parameter int a, it is declaring it in local scope of the function. When calling the function, the value provided as the argument
is assigned into this name. That's how passing argument to function works.

Also note: you could change

```
void fun(int a) {
   // some code
}
```

with

```
void fun(int asdf) {
   // some code with asdf instead of a identifiers
}
```

and it should do the same thing without changing anything elsewhere.

Comment: I do not address the problems of buscador, but this is the first thing you need to understand

Comment: you can look at first code snippet here too https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/parameter-passing-techniques-in-c-cpp/